# How to create a file using user input in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, pug, fs

I have a text area, where the user type in their text. Once they click save the content in the text area is send to the server side. In the server side I want to use the content to create a file. I have a variable called "usercode" which holds the content of the text area. I create a file,

```
fs.wirteFile(name + "java", usercode, function(){})
```

Name the file name, given by user. This does create a file, however the only thing in the file is "[object Object]".

here is my client side I am using jade:

```
extends layout

block content
div(id="ineditortxt")
    h1(name="headings") #{title}
    a(href='/signout', class='text-center new-account') Sign Out
    div(id="editor")
        |public class #{title}{
        |   public static void main(String[] args) {
        |   
        |   }
        |}
    script(src="src/ace.js", type="text/javascript")
    script(type="text/javascript").
        //var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var editor=ace.edit("editor");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
        editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/java");
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#save").click(function(event){
                var content = editor.getValue();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/getcode',
                    type:'POST',
                    data: content,
                    jsonpCallback: 'callback'
                });
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
                });
            });
    form(name="Save", id = "save")
        input(type="submit", value="Save")
    div(id="result")
        |
```

Here is the server side i didn't include all the code, just the one related to this question:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var param = require('express-params');
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
    router.post('/editor', function(req, res){
  name = req.body.newname;
  res.render('Editor', {title: "" + name});
});

router.post('/getcode', function(req, res){
  var usercode = req.body;
  fs.writeFile(name + ".java",  usercode, function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else{
      console.log("The file is saved!");
    }
  })
  res.send({code: "" + usercode});
  console.log(usercode);
});

return router;
}
```

Comment: Use JSON.stringify(usercode) ?

Comment: This works except if the user typed in:  `System.out.println("Hello World");` Then the file is saved as: `{"System.out.println(\"Hello World\");":""}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On client side the code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#save").click(function(event){
                var content = editor.getValue();
                console.log("This is content: " + content);
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/getcode',
                    type:'POST',
                    data: {'code': content},
                    processData: 'false',
                });
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
                });
            });
```

on the server side the code should be:

```
 router.post('/getcode', function(req, res){
  var usercode = req.body.code;
  newname = name+".java";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually writing the `req.body` object to the file which is a JSON object to access the post data in your request.

You need to access the post data by form field name inside that object so if you have a form field named "myField", it's data will be available in `req.body.myField`

If you want to just write the whole object to the file, you need to first stringify the JSON object using `JSON.stringify(req.body)`

`JSON.stringify` is going to escape the string which you can fix by unescaping it using `unescape(string)`

Comment: This works except if the user typed in: `System.out.println("Hello World");` Then the file is saved as:`{"System.out.println(\"Hello World\");":""}`

Comment: @Sujinthan Updated by answer.

Comment: Doesn't work: this is my code `fs.writeFile(name + ".java", unescape(JSON.stringify(req.body)), function(err){`